# Set variable on back button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have a function I dont want to run if the broswer back button was clicked.  I am attempting to use something like the below:

```
var backButtonClicked = false;

window.onpopstate = function() {
    alert("Back clicked");
    backButtonClicked = true;
};
```

then later I am trying to use the variable like:

```
if(!backButtonClicked) {
   //run function if not back button clicked
}
```

However with the code above the alert is not getting fired when I hit the back button.

```
window.onpopstate = function() {
    alert("back clicked");
    backButtonClicked = true;
};
history.pushState({}, '');
```

With the code above the alert gets fired when I click the back button, however the browser doesnt navigate back to the previous page unless I click the back button for the second time.  Is there something I am doing incorrect here or is there a better approach to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: I don't think I understand the scenario well enough to offer help, so please correct me if my understanding is incorrect. You have 2 pages, say A.html and B.html, each of which load the script you mention. If you navigate from page A.html to B.html and then hit the back button, then you want to set a variable on B.html to be read on A.html to prevent a function from being executed once A.html loads. Is that more or less the scenario? And if correct, do you also want to prevent the function from running on B.html if you navigate from A.html to B.html by hitting the back button?

Comment: @GPicazo - yes the scenario you have outlined is what I need to try and acheive

Answer (score 0):

My coding skills are not very good when I have very little time to type. But maybe an eventlistener would be another approach to the problem you can maybe consider?

For examples and reference from an excellent source:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Hope this helps, and good luck!